# Android write PDF file whith itextpdf pt-BR language

Tags: android, pdf, encoding, character-encoding, itextpdf

I need write PDF File, and I use this sample(http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html) with this version "itextpdf-5.4.1.jar".

This create the PDF file, but when the word has "você" write this "vocÃª".

I find this code but has not work:

Document document;
...
...
document.addLanguage("pt-BR");

How set encoding or language to Brasil?

Thanks!

Comment: As your single letter 'ê' becomes two characters, could it be that your source file is UTF8 encoded but your compiler assumes some single byte encoding?

Comment: This is explained in great detail in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html); this is a free ebook with answers to questions such as [Can't get Czech characters while generating a PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631815/cant-get-czech-characters-while-generating-a-pdf). In your case, your encoding problem is probably caused already at the moment you are reading your source file.

Comment: Thanks for all! My problem was really the Android Studio File encoding, how @mkl and bruno-lowagie has explained "This is not really an iText question. This is a pure encoding question." Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my answer to [Divide page in 2 parts so we can fill each with different source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502315/divide-page-in-2-parts-so-we-can-fill-each-with-different-source) (this is year another question answered in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html)). In this example, we read a series of text files that are stored in UTF-8. To achieve this, we use this method:

```
public Phrase createPhrase(String path) throws IOException {
    Phrase p = new Phrase();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF8"));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        p.add(str);
    }
    in.close();
    return p;
}
```

If you remove the `"UTF8"` and if you read that text as if it were ASCII, then you'd get the same behavior you are describing in your question: each byte would be treated as a single character whereas you have characters that require two bytes.

This is not really an iText question. This is a pure encoding question.

Comment: Thanks @bruno-lowagie this works, I set correct encoding and now is correct my text in PDF.